# Get-ADComputer -filter * -property $Variable

Tags: powershell

Really baffled by this one. I have a Windows form with checkboxes based on AD attribute names. Once OK I run:

```
$ADVARIABLES = @()
Get-Variable -Name OBJ* | ?{ $_.Value.Checkstate -eq 1  } | %{ $ADVARIABLES += $_.Value.Name }
```

To get the attribute names.

If I run:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property $ADVARIABLES | select $ADVARIABLES
```

I get the kind of results I'd expect to see.

If I run:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property $ADVARIABLES | select $ADVARIABLES
```

I get:

> Get-ADComputer : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Properties'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.

The attributes on my checkboxes for Get-AdUser include:

Mail, Manager, Department, Title, CanonicalName, Phone, Mobile, HomeDirectory

The attributes for PC are:

SamAccountName, CanonicalName, IPv4Address, Enabled, OperatingSystem

Any ideas? There's definitely no rogue attribute on the `$ADVARIABLES` tag, it's just being a royal pain in the bum.

**EDIT:**

Here's the script in full. Working fine for AD Users, not for Computers:

```
# Adds .NET assemby's and turns on visual themes in standard PowerShell.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()



# Creates the parent form
$ADREPORT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$ADREPORT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 270,175 )
$ADREPORT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 800,400 )
$ADREPORT.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$ADREPORT.BackColor     = "Lavender"
$ADREPORT.Font          = "Calibri, 8.5"


# This creates a label for the title
$ADHEADER               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$ADHEADER.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 30,20 )
$ADHEADER.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 180,20 )
$ADHEADER.Font          = New-Object System.Drawing.Font( "Calibri",11,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold )
$ADHEADER.Text          = "Choose your attributes"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $ADHEADER )


# This creates a label for the sub-header
$ADTEXT                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$ADTEXT.Location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 30,50 )
$ADTEXT.Size            = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 300,40 )
$ADTEXT.Text            = "From the list below, select as many attributes as you like to generate a CSV report:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $ADTEXT )


# Active Directory Users label
$OBJUSERTXT             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJUSERTXT.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,100 )
$OBJUSERTXT.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJUSERTXT.Text        = "USERS:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJUSERTXT ) 

# Active Directory Users checkbox - Checked by default
$USERBOX                = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$USERBOX.Location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,98 )
$USERBOX.Size           = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$USERBOX.TabIndex       = 0
$USERBOX.Checked        = $TRUE
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $USERBOX )



# Active Directory Computers label
$PCXT                   = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$PCXT.Location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 150,100 )
$PCXT.Size              = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$PCXT.Text              = "COMPUTERS:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $PCXT )

# Active Directory Computers checkbox
$OBJPCBOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJPCBOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 230,98 )
$OBJPCBOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJPCBOX.TabIndex      = 9
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJPCBOX )



# SamAccountName label
$OBJ01TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ01TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,120 )
$OBJ01TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ01TXT.Text          = "Username:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ01TXT ) 

# SamAccountName checkbox
$OBJ01BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ01BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,118 )
$OBJ01BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ01BOX.TabIndex      = 1
$OBJ01BOX.Checked       = $TRUE
$OBJ01BOX.Name          = "SamAccountName"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ01BOX )



# Full Name label
$OBJ02TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ02TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,140 )
$OBJ02TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ02TXT.Text          = "Full name:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ02TXT )

# Full Name checkbox
$OBJ02BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
$OBJ02BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,138 )
$OBJ02BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ02BOX.TabIndex      = 2
$OBJ02BOX.Name          = "Name"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ02BOX )



# First Name label
$OBJ03TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ03TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,160 )
$OBJ03TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ03TXT.Text          = "First name:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ03TXT )

# First Name checkbox
$OBJ03BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ03BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,158 )
$OBJ03BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ03BOX.TabIndex      = 3
$OBJ03BOX.Name          = "GivenName"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ03BOX )




# Surname label
$OBJ04TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ04TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,180 )
$OBJ04TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ04TXT.Text          = "Surname:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ04TXT )

# Surname checkbox
$OBJ04BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ04BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,178 )
$OBJ04BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ04BOX.TabIndex      = 4
$OBJ04BOX.Name          = "Surname"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ04BOX )




# Department label
$OBJ05TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ05TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,200 )
$OBJ05TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ05TXT.Text          = "Department:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ05TXT )

# Department checkbox
$OBJ05BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ05BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,198 )
$OBJ05BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ05BOX.TabIndex      = 5
$OBJ05BOX.Name          = "Department"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ05BOX )




# Job Title label
$OBJ06TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ06TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,220 )
$OBJ06TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ06TXT.Text          = "Job Title:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ06TXT )

# Job Title checkbox
$OBJ06BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ06BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,218 )
$OBJ06BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ06BOX.TabIndex      = 6
$OBJ06BOX.Name          = "Title"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ06BOX )




# Manager Label
$OBJ07TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ07TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,240 )
$OBJ07TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ07TXT.Text          = "Manager:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ07TXT )

# Manager checkbox
$OBJ07BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ07BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,238 )
$OBJ07BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ07BOX.TabIndex      = 7
$OBJ07BOX.Name          = "Manager"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ07BOX )




# IP Address label
$OBJ18TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ18TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,280 )
$OBJ18TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ18TXT.Text          = "IP Address:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ18TXT )

# IP Address checkbox
$OBJ18BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ18BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,278 )
$OBJ18BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ18BOX.TabIndex      = 19
$OBJ18BOX.Name          = "IPv4Address"
$OBJ18BOX.Enabled       = $FALSE
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ18BOX )



# Home Drive Label
$OBJ09TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ09TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 150,120 )
$OBJ09TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ09TXT.Text          = "Home Drive:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ09TXT )

# Home Drive Checkbox
$OBJ09BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ09BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 230,118 )
$OBJ09BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ09BOX.TabIndex      = 10
$OBJ09BOX.Name          = "HomeDirectory"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ09BOX )




# Email label
$OBJ10TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ10TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 150,140 )
$OBJ10TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ10TXT.Text          = "Email:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ10TXT )

# Email checkbox
$OBJ10BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ10BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 230,138 )
$OBJ10BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ10BOX.TabIndex      = 11
$OBJ10BOX.Name          = "Mail"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ10BOX )



# Phone label
$OBJ11TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ11TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 150,160 )
$OBJ11TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ11TXT.Text          = "Phone:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ11TXT )

# Phone checkbox
$OBJ11BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ11BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 230,158 )
$OBJ11BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ11BOX.TabIndex      = 12
$OBJ11BOX.Name          = "OfficePhone"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ11BOX )



# Mobile phone label
$OBJ12TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ12TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 150,180 )
$OBJ12TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ12TXT.Text          = "Mobile:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ12TXT )

# Mobile phone checkbox
$OBJ12BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ12BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 230,178 )
$OBJ12BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ12BOX.TabIndex      = 13
$OBJ12BOX.Name          = "MobilePhone"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ12BOX )




# Created label
$OBJ13TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ13TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 150,200 )
$OBJ13TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ13TXT.Text          = "Creation Date:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ13TXT )

# Created checkbox
$OBJ13BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ13BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 230,198 )
$OBJ13BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ13BOX.TabIndex      = 14
$OBJ13BOX.Name          = "Created"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ13BOX )



# Modified label
$OBJ14TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ14TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 150,220 )
$OBJ14TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ14TXT.Text          = "Modified Date:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ14TXT )

# Modified checkbox
$OBJ14BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ14BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 230,218 )
$OBJ14BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ14BOX.TabIndex      = 15
$OBJ14BOX.Name          = "Modified"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ14BOX )



# Password label
$OBJ15TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ15TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 150,240 )
$OBJ15TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ15TXT.Text          = "Password Set:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ15TXT )

# Password checkbox
$OBJ15BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ15BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 230,238 )
$OBJ15BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ15BOX.TabIndex      = 16
$OBJ15BOX.Name          = "PasswordLastSet"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ15BOX )



# Enabled label
$OBJ08TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ08TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 150,260 )
$OBJ08TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ08TXT.Text          = "Enabled Status:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ08TXT )

# Enable checkbox
$OBJ08BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ08BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 230,258 )
$OBJ08BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ08BOX.TabIndex      = 17
$OBJ08BOX.Name          = "Enabled"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ08BOX )



#This creates a label for the 18th attribute - Operating System
$OBJ17TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ17TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 150,280 )
$OBJ17TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ17TXT.Text          = "OS:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ17TXT )

#This creates the checkbox for the 18th attribute - Operating System
$OBJ17BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
 $OBJ17BOX.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 230,278 )
$OBJ17BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ17BOX.TabIndex      = 18
 $OBJ17BOX.Name         = "OperatingSystem"
 $OBJ17BOX.Enabled      = $FALSE
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ17BOX )



# OU Label
$OBJ16TXT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJ16TXT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,260 )
$OBJ16TXT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJ16TXT.Text          = "OU:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ16TXT )

# OU Checkbox
$OBJ16BOX               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJ16BOX.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,258 )
$OBJ16BOX.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJ16BOX.TabIndex      = 8
$OBJ16BOX.Name          = "CanonicalName"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJ16BOX )




# OK Button
$OK                     = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OK.Location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 30,315 )
$OK.Size                = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 75,23 )
$OK.ForeColor           = "Green"
$OK.Text                = "OK"
$OK.DialogResult        = "OK" 
$OK.add_Click( { $ADREPORT.Close() } ) 
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OK )

# Cancel button
$CANCEL                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CANCEL.Location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point( 160,315 )
$CANCEL.Size            = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 75,23 )
$CANCEL.ForeColor       = "Red"
$CANCEL.Text            = "Cancel"
$CANCEL.DialogResult    = "Cancel"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $CANCEL )



# If PC checkbox ticked, grey out user specific attributes
$OBJPCBOX.Add_CheckStateChanged( {
IF ( $OBJPCBOX.Checked )
     { $USERBOX.Checked    = $FALSE                                  # AD User box
         $OBJ02BOX.Enabled = $FALSE ; $OBJ02BOX.Checked = $FALSE     # Full name
         $OBJ03BOX.Enabled = $FALSE ; $OBJ03BOX.Checked = $FALSE     # First name
         $OBJ04BOX.Enabled = $FALSE ; $OBJ04BOX.Checked = $FALSE     # Surname
         $OBJ05BOX.Enabled = $FALSE ; $OBJ05BOX.Checked = $FALSE     # Department
         $OBJ06BOX.Enabled = $FALSE ; $OBJ06BOX.Checked = $FALSE     # Job Title
         $OBJ07BOX.Enabled = $FALSE ; $OBJ07BOX.Checked = $FALSE     # Manager
         $OBJ09BOX.Enabled = $FALSE ; $OBJ09BOX.Checked = $FALSE     # HomeDirectory
         $OBJ10BOX.Enabled = $FALSE ; $OBJ10BOX.Checked = $FALSE     # Mail
         $OBJ11BOX.Enabled = $FALSE ; $OBJ11BOX.Checked = $FALSE     # Phone
         $OBJ12BOX.Enabled = $FALSE ; $OBJ12BOX.Checked = $FALSE     # Mobile
         $OBJ17BOX.Enabled = $TRUE  ; $OBJ18BOX.Enabled = $TRUE }    # OS & IP Address

# IF User box ticked, untick PC box and un-grey user specific attributes
IF ( $OBJPCBOX.Checked -eq $FALSE ) 
     { $USERBOX.Checked    = $TRUE  ; $OBJ02BOX.Enabled = $TRUE
         $OBJ03BOX.Enabled = $TRUE  ; $OBJ04BOX.Enabled = $TRUE
         $OBJ05BOX.Enabled = $TRUE  ; $OBJ06BOX.Enabled = $TRUE
         $OBJ07BOX.Enabled = $TRUE  ; $OBJ09BOX.Enabled = $TRUE
         $OBJ10BOX.Enabled = $TRUE  ; $OBJ11BOX.Enabled = $TRUE
         $OBJ12BOX.Enabled = $TRUE
         $OBJ17BOX.Enabled = $FALSE ; $OBJ18BOX.Enabled = $FALSE }

} ) # CLOSES $OBJPCBOX.Add_CheckStateChanged( {


# IF user box ticked, untick PC box
$USERBOX.Add_CheckStateChanged( {
IF ( $USERBOX.Checked -eq $TRUE )
     { $OBJPCBOX.Checked = $FALSE } } )




# Launch the checkbox form.
$ADREPORT.Add_Shown( { $ADREPORT.Activate() } )



# When you've pressed ok...

# /// If you choose ADUsers then first create two empty variables; populate $ADVAIRABLES with the name of each checkbox 
#         ticked.
#         Perform an unfiltered search of Active Directory users and select just the attributes from the checkboxes. This 
#         is measured for visual feedback.
#         If the Manager attribute is checked, this comes back in DN form ( CN=Graham Jordan,OU=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL ), 
#         so run a Get-Aduser against each DN to bring back the full name.
#         The manager conversion is wrapped up in Write-Progress to give you a visual impression of how far into the change,
#         since this takes a while.
#         If the OU attribute is ticked ( CanonicalName ), then run a replace on each line to remove the domain name, and 
#         the users full name leaving just Users/...
#         Finally exports a CSV to your user profile in "AD Report for Users - 28 02 2018 - 12.45.csv" format.


IF ( ( $ADREPORT.ShowDialog() ) -eq "OK" )
   { IF ( $USERBOX.Checked )
        { $ADVARIABLES = @()
          $USERS             = @()

          Write-Host "Performing a search of all users on Active Directory. This part can take a minute or so" -f Green ; "" 
          Get-Variable -Name OBJ* | ?{ $_.Value.Checkstate -eq 1    } | %{ $ADVARIABLES += $_.Value.Name }

          $SECONDS = ( Measure-Command {
          $USERS    += Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property $ADVARIABLES | select $ADVARIABLES | sort Name } ).seconds

          Write-Host $USERS.Count user accounts identified in $SECONDS seconds. -f Green ; ""


          IF ( $USERS.Manager -notlike $NULL ) 
             { $USERS | foreach-object -begin { $COUNT = 0 } -process { 
               $USER = $_

               IF ( $USER.Manager )
                  { $USER.Manager = ( ( Get-ADUser $USER.Manager ).Name ).ToString() }
                    $COUNT = $COUNT + 1
                    Write-Progress -Activity "Altering Manager DN's to Manager Name" -Status "Progress: $(
                    $USER.Name )" -PercentComplete ( $COUNT / $USERS.count * 100 ) } }


          IF ( $USER.CanonicalName )
             { Foreach ( $USER in $USERS )
                       { $USER.CanonicalName = $USER.CanonicalName.Substring( $USER.CanonicalName.IndexOf( "/" ) +1 )
                         $USER.CanonicalName = $USER.CanonicalName -replace "/$( $USER.Name )" } }


          $USERS | Export-Csv "$env:USERPROFILE\AD Report for Users - $( Get-Date -Format "dd MMM yyyy - hh.mm" ).csv" -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Force }


IF ( $OBJPCBOX.Checked )
   { $ADVARIABLES = @()
     Get-Variable -Name OBJ* | ?{ $_.Value.Checkstate -eq 1    } | %{ $ADVARIABLES += $_.Value.Name }

     Write-Host "Performing a search of all computers on Active Directory. This part can take a minute or so" -f Green ; ""

     $PCS  = @()
     $PCS += Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties $ADVARIABLES | select $ADVARIABLES | sort SamAccountName


     IF ( $PCS.CanonicalName )
        { Foreach ( $PC in $PCS )
                  { $PC.CanonicalName = $PC.CanonicalName.Substring( $PC.CanonicalName.IndexOf( "/" ) +1 ) 
                    $PC.CanonicalName = $PC.CanonicalName -replace "/$( $PC.SamAccountName )$" } }

     $PCS | Export-Csv "$env:USERPROFILE\AD Report for Computers - $( Get-Date -Format "dd MMM yyyy - hh.mm" ).csv" -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Force }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `-Properties` instead of `-Properties`?

Comment: What is the value of `$ADVariables` when you call `Get-ADComputer`? If you pass an empty array for the `-Property` parameter I get the same error. Example: `Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties @()`

Comment: @ShawnEsterman I've added the whole script so you can try it for yourself. No editing needed for it to work. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was annoying. GUIs are disgusting. So your issue is that if you ran the following command:

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity PC01 -Properties 'Created','PasswordLastSet',''
```

It will throw an error because ONE of the properties is a null/empty string. You had a null/empty string in `$ADVARIABLES` which caused your error.

Per your script I made a modification:

```
Get-Variable -Name OBJ* | ?{ $_.Value.Checkstate -eq 1    } | %{
    Write-Host -Object "Adding property '$($_.Value.Name)' from $($_.Name)"
    $ADVARIABLES += $_.Value.Name
}
```

This provided me with the following output:

```
Adding property 'SamAccountName' from OBJ01BOX
Adding property 'Created' from OBJ13BOX
Adding property 'PasswordLastSet' from OBJ15BOX
Adding property '' from OBJPCBOX
```

You will need to probably rename `$OBJPCBOX` or create a better filter when you're populating `$ADVARIABLES`.

Comment: GUIs are disgusting for you, for the Service Desk they're the only thing that prevents them logging calls. 
Aside from the comment that can only be construed as insulting, thank you for the help. Frustrating when something as much as a simple naming mistake can throw the whole thing out.

Cheers

Comment: Ha I work in a service desk, but we do custom PowerShell modules instead of GUIs to look up information. The disgusting part was more the amount of lines required to make something do such a simple task.